# Problem with MySQL full text search in combination with OR?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a table *Document* with a full text index *headline_idx* on two columns, *headline* and *text* where the text is a `MEDIUMTEXT` column, there is also some other fields, one of the named lang.

If I do the following select:

```
select * from Document where lang= 'en' AND match(headLine,text) against ("test")
```

everything works OK, the fulltext index is used as expected, BUT if I change the AND to an OR like this:

```
select * from Document where lang= 'en' OR match(headLine,text) against ("test")
```

the full text index is NOT used, it's not even part of the `possible_keys` if I do an `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` which makes any index hints useless.

I would be perfectly happy to add the third column to the full text index, but in the real case that column is in another table. I run version 5.1.35 of MySQL.

Any ideas on what's going on?

Comment: I think you forgot to change the "AND" to an "OR"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from MySql reference:
[Index Merge](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-merge-optimization.html) is not applicable to fulltext indexes. We plan to extend it to cover these in a future MySQL release.

This particular query can be rephrased with a union and then it will use indexes:

```
select * from Document where lang= 'en' UNION
select * from Document where match(headLine,text) against ("test")
```